# How to find the last value ordered by a different column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table `MyTable` has columns: `QuoteID, ControlNo, Premium, ExpirationDate`

I need to create a measure that would grab the `SUM(Premium)` and `EffectiveDate` should be `<= Today()` and last `ExpirationDate` (ordered by `QuoteID DESC`) should be `>= Today()`.

How can I translate below statement to DAX?

In SQL, I would do this way:

```
select sum(Premium) as Premium
from MyTable t
where EffectiveDate <= GETDATE() and
      (select top 1 t2.ExpirationDate
       from MyTable t2
       where t2.ControlNo = t.controlno
       order by t.quoteid desc) >= GETDATE()
```

How can I write it in DAX?

I've tried this, but it's not working properly:

```
Premium =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( fact_Premium[Premium] ),
    FILTER (
        fact_Premium,
        fact_Premium[EffectiveDate] <= TODAY () &&
        TOPN ( 1, ALL ( fact_Premium[ExpirationDate] ), 
                  fact_Premium[QuoteID], ASC ) >= TODAY ()
    )
)
```

**UPDATE:**

Trying to create calculated table from fact_Premium dataset, but still not sure how can I filter it

```
In_Force Premium = 
    FILTER(
        ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(
           //Grouping necessary columns
            fact_Premium,
            fact_Premium[QuoteID],
            fact_Premium[Division],
            fact_Premium[Office],
            dim_Company[CompanyGUID],
            fact_Premium[LineGUID],
            fact_Premium[ProducerGUID],
            fact_Premium[StateID],
            fact_Premium[ExpirationDate]
                  ),    
            "Premium", CALCULATE(
                                SUM(fact_Premium[Premium])
                                ),
            "ControlNo", CALCULATE(
                            DISTINCTCOUNT(fact_Premium[ControlNo])
                                  )

   ), // Here I need to make sure TODAY() falls between fact_Premium[EffectiveDate] and (SELECT TOP 1 fact_Premium[ExpirationDate] ORDE BY QuoteID DESC)
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with the DAX here.

First, when you use `TOPN`, your ordering expression (3rd argument) can only reference rows in the table you are operating on (2nd argument), so only using the `[ExpirationDate]` column there won't work. I think you probably want `fact_Premium` instead of `ALL ( fact_Premium[ExpirationDate] )`.

Second, the `TOPN` function returns a table rather than a single value, so you need to access the column you want somehow. One option would be to use an iterator like `SUMX` or `MAXX`:

```
MAXX( TOPN(...), fact_Premium[ExpirationDate] )
```

You could also use `SELECTCOLUMNS` which will coerce a single row, single column table to just be a value:

```
SELECTCOLUMNS( TOPN(...), "ExpirationDate", fact_Premium[ExpirationDate] )
```

---

I can't guarantee that this will work perfectly, but it should get you closer to your goal:

```
Premium =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( fact_Premium[Premium] ),
    FILTER (
        fact_Premium,
        fact_Premium[EffectiveDate] <= TODAY () &&
        SUMX( TOPN ( 1, fact_Premium, fact_Premium[QuoteID], DESC ),
              fact_Premium[ExpirationDate] )
            >= TODAY ()
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you Alexis. Great explanation. Unfortunately Premium number is too high. 
I thought maybe I can create separate  calculated table from` fact_Premium` dataset?
I posted UPDATE